# Error uploading image to firebase storage in React Native [ Firebase 9.6.2]

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, cloud, firebase-storage

so i'm trying to upload an image to firebase storage (a local photo from the source file directory - path: same path as .js). The problem is that in firebase storage the image appears to be corrupted and every picture have 9 bytes [firebase storage image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqEYr.png) . The authentication and firestore works perfectly, this is my configuration file: [firebase config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhOiM.png) and this is the code:

```
const uploadPhoto = async() => {
    // console.log(image);
    // const uploadUri = image;
    // let filename = uploadUri.substring(uploadUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
     
    const metadata = {
      //path: '../../firebase_image.jpg',
      contentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };
    const photog = `./photo.jpg`;
    console.log(photog);
    console.log(uploadUri);
    const storageRef;
    storageRef=ref(storage, 'photogra.jpg');//filename+
    uploadBytes(storageRef, photog, metadata).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
    });
   
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the information from this amazing tutorial and worked fine for me
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-yXO46WDak&lc=z22ph5dhssfqufkcxacdp430segloszlmvuqlp1seplw03c010c

Try with this:

```
const uploadImageFirebase = async () =>{

  const nameImage =  new Date().toISOString();
  
  const img = await fetch(image);
  const bytes = await img.blob();

  try {
    await uploadBytes(ref_con, bytes); 

    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    } finally {
      //
    }        
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the contents of your 9-byte file, it'll like be `"photo.jpg"`.

Since you're passing `"photo.jpg"` to `uploadBytes`, it uploads that strings as the contents of the new file. It does not know how to load the file at that path.

You will either need to pass a local `File` or `Buffer` (which you'll usually get from a file picker or something like that), or load the data from the file yourself and pass the contents to `uploadBytes`.

Comment: and how should i do this i really don't know how to get pass the file into uploadbytes or a buffer

Comment: As said, you'll typically get this form a component like a file picker, like `react-native-image-picker` in this article https://dev.to/younesh1989/upload-files-using-react-native-and-firebase-part-2-571o